# How to deploy a contract in Mainnnet (not Alfanet!) Tezos? I have a contract code for Fi, a working node on the Digital Ocean. What should I do next?

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity, deploy

I have a contract code for Fi, a working Mainnet node on the Digital Ocean. What should I do next? Please explain in detail because I have little experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to build the deploy command using https://fi-code.com/ .

You can build the command by specifying the contract code in fi, the initial storage and balance, and the manager, then pressing "Deploy" button.

Test deployment in Alphanet is **strongly recommended** before doing this directly to the Mainnet.

Comment: What should I write in the column Storage.Value and Storage.StartTime ?